# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

In my ionic3 program, there is an error `Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')`

Source code is:

.ts

```
... 
d = [
    "M", start.x, start.y,
    "A", opts.radius, opts.radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y,
    "L", opts.cx, opts.cy,
    "Z",

    "M", start2.x, start2.y,
    "A", cutout_radius, cutout_radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end2.x, end2.y,
    "L", opts.cx, opts.cy,
    "Z"
  ].join(" ");
document.getElementById('red').setAttribute("d", d);
```

.html

```
<svg viewBox="0 200 400 400" width="400" height="400">
  <path id="red" fill="red" stroke="none" fill-rule="evenodd" />
</svg>
```

.scss

```
svg {
  background: #ddd;
  display:block;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to apply operations on DOM before it gets rendered. To achieve the same, you can put your code inside `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, which makes sure the DOM is ready/rendered before you modify it.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const d = [
    "M", start.x, start.y,
    "A", opts.radius, opts.radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y,
    "L", opts.cx, opts.cy,
    "Z",

    "M", start2.x, start2.y,
    "A", cutout_radius, cutout_radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end2.x, end2.y,
    "L", opts.cx, opts.cy,
    "Z"
  ].join(" ");
  document.getElementById('red').setAttribute("d", d);
}
```

> Note:- Won't recommend to do direct DOM operations inside angular,
> please read [Working with DOM in Angular: unexpected
> consequences](https://indepth.dev/posts/1134/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques)